# Adding MVVM Light to SL5 (via NuGet) project breaks Application.Resources in App.xaml

Tags: mvvm-light

After I add MVVM light, the app.xaml makes you give the default ResourceDictionary an x:key. Even then I can't seem to get the Styles under MainPage.xaml to resolve to the key I provided. I tried to cheat and use Blend, but it crashes every time I open the modified project.

Steps to repro: Create new project (SL5 Navigation Application), then add MVVM Light via Add Library Package Reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah. ok... simply move  inside the existing  node. The error message made me think I needed to name the existing node and create a 2nd node.

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <Application 
>     x:Class="ValidationClient.App" 
>     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
>     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
>     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
>     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
>     xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ValidationClient.ViewModel" 
>     mc:Ignorable="d">   <Application.Resources>
>     <ResourceDictionary>
>       <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
>         <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/Styles.xaml" />
>       </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>      <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
>     </ResourceDictionary>   </Application.Resources> </Application>
```